# htaccess: Redirect www.subdomian.example.com to subdomain.example.com

Tags: http, .htaccess, apache2

I'm attempting to redirect all www.subdomain.example.com traffic to subdomain.example.com. Currently, if someone uses the www, they receive an error that the server isn't found. I attempted to add the following to the .htaccess file:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, the error still occurs. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve this with rewriting. The server is not reachable via "www." which technically is a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common way to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.##domain##
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://##domain##/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace `##domain##` with your domain. Add the `[NC]` flag if you wish.